# Overwrite sass function for bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

I am trying to modify bootstrap 5 function `color-contrast`.
I want it to sometimes return hardcoded values based on `$background` parameter. I can do that just by modifying function itself, but since I have bootstrap in `node_modules`, I want to avoid it and to somehow overwrite this function in my custom code.

How do I overwrite function with my own in sass? Or how to solve this otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. First of all redefining function overwrites it's previous behaviour. My problem was, that I was inserting "bootstrap" main scss file and then again all the files, that were supposed to be inserted and that caused chaos.
In the end I just import my custom file `my_custom_functions` with overwritten function after importing `functions` of bootstrap, then the rest of it. For example:

```
@import "functions";
//here
@import "my_custom_functions";

@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "utilities";

// Layout & components
@import "root";
@import "reboot";
@import "type";
@import "images";
@import "containers";
...
```

Answer (score -1):

[This function](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/theming/#color-contrast) will generate some class depending on colors defined by your variables.
I suppose you could create your own function based on the same loop to override its behavior.

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .swatch-#{$color} {
    /* Add the behavior you want */
  }
}
```

Then, sass knows how to organize your code, you don't loose the initial behavior, but you can extend it.

Comment: I already had implementation for this. I needed way to integrate it nicely without modifying original bootstrap code.

Comment: So your problem is not how to override functions, but how to import bootstrap correctly with Sass, then override.

Comment: Yes, but I think it is called overwrite, not override :-) Overriding is when using inheritance.